# Using Archimedes-Riemann Theorem to prove integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Here is an excerpt from a book I am reading. There is one portion that I don't understand, which I explain afterwards:

---

For the rectangle $\mathbf{I} = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ in the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, define $$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } (x, y) \text{ is  in } \mathbf{I} \text{ and } y > x \\[1em]
0 & \text{ if } (x, y) \text { is in } \mathbf{I} \text{ and } y \leq x \end{cases} $$

We use the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem to show that the function $f : \mathbf{I} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable. For a natural number $k$, let $P_{k}$ be the partition of the interval $[0, 1]$ into $k$ intervals of equal length $1/k$ and define the partition $\mathbf{P}_{k}$ of $\mathbf{I}$ to be $(P_k, P_k)$. Observe that the only nonzero terms in the sum $U(f, \mathbf{P}_{k}) - L(f, \mathbf{P}_k)$ that can possibly be nonzero are those arising from the rectangles in the partition $\mathbf{P}_{k}$ that intersect the diagonal. Each of these contributions is $1/k^2$, and there are fewer than $2k$ of such rectangles. Hence,

$$U(f, \mathbf{P}_k) - L(f, \mathbf{P}_k) < 2/k.$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} [U(f,\mathbf{P}_k) - L(f,\mathbf{P}_k)] = 0,$$

and integrability follows by the Archimedes Riemann Theorem.

---

**My question:**

I don't think I'm quite understanding whether the numbers $1/k^2$ and $2k$ are coming from. I would appreciate some clarity here. I think the $1/k^2$ comes from the product of two equally-lengthed intervals, but I'm not sure what they mean by the contribution.

Thanks

Comment: You're right about the $1/k^2.$  Each positive summand "contributes" its value o the total.  He's just saying that there are at most $2k$ positive terms, and the value of each is $1/k^2,$ so the um is $<2/k$.

Comment: Why are there at most $2k$ positive terms? I don't see how to get that number

Comment: I'm not sure how $U(f,P_k), L(f,P_k)$ are defined, so I can't tell you that.

Comment: $U(f, \mathbf{P}_{k}) = \sum_{\mathbf{J} \text{ in } \mathbf{P}_{k}} M(f, \mathbf{J}) \cdot \text{vol } \mathbf{J}$ where $M(f, \mathbf{J}) = \text{sup}\{f(x) \mid x \text{ is in } \mathbf{J}\}$

Comment: There are $k$ squares that overlap the diagonal.  Above each square (except the last) is a square that intersects the diagonal in a single point.  On this square, $\sup{f}=1,\ \inf{f}=0$.  That gives $2k-1$ squares in all.  The squares below the diagonal don't come into it, because $f\equiv0$ on and below the diagonal.